# Can not we release lower version using "mvn release"?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3

I have already released 1.100,1.200,1.400 in repo using `"mvn release"` command.

Can I release 1.300 version using `"mvn release"`? It will create any problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK the release-plugin increments the version so that might result in problems. You could trying to deploy manually though (`mvn deploy`).

Comment: Really using Maven 2? Why not using Maven 3+?